# Most efficient way of extracting data from xml using lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, python-3.3

I have the following snippet of a large xml file. I would like to extract specific namespaces, such as `xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"`. currently i am able to do this like follows:

```
tree = etree.parse(file)
    for element in tree.getiterator('{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record'):
        for leaf in element.getiterator('{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}subject'):
            print(leaf)
```

the problem is that I wish to get data for multiple tags in the {http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/} namespace. I would also like to simplify things and have been looking at how to use xpath, but cannot seem to figure it out. Can I use xpath and if so how, and more importantly is it better for my goals?

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>



<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/
 http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
<responseDate>2013-08-15T23:24:55Z</responseDate>
<request verb="ListRecords" resumptionToken="0/500/121403/nsdl_dc/null/null/null">http://nsdldev.org/oai</request>

<!-- Showing records 501 through 1000 out of 121403 total  -->

<ListRecords>


  <record>
    <header>
      <identifier>oai:nsdl.org:2200/20110926115158975T</identifier>
      <datestamp>2013-05-29T16:44:49Z</datestamp>
       <setSpec>ncs-NSDL-COLLECTION-000-003-112-056</setSpec>
      </header>
    <metadata>
    <nsdl_dc:nsdl_dc xmlns:nsdl_dc="http://ns.nsdl.org/nsdl_dc_v1.02/"
                 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                 xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
                 xmlns:lar="http://ns.nsdl.org/schemas/dc/lar"
                 xmlns:ieee="http://www.ieee.org/xsd/LOMv1p0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 schemaVersion="1.02.020"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://ns.nsdl.org/nsdl_dc_v1.02/ http://ns.nsdl.org/schemas/nsdl_dc/nsdl_dc_v1.02.xsd">
   <lar:readiness xsi:type="lar:Ready">Fully ready</lar:readiness>
   <dc:identifier xsi:type="dct:URI">http://www.exo.net/~emuller/activities/Hot%20Sauce%20Hot%20Spots.pdf</dc:identifier>
   <dc:relation xsi:type="nsdl_dc:NSDLPartnerURL">http://howtosmile.org/record/4427</dc:relation>
   <dc:title>Hot Sauce Hot Spots</dc:title>
   <dc:description>In this activity, learners model hot spot island formation, orientation and progression with condiments. Learners squirt a thick condiment sauce on a coarsely woven fabric to model how volcanic island hot spots form.</dc:description>
   <dc:subject>Geoscience</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Earth system science</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Geoscience</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Earth system science</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Geoscience</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Geoscience</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Geoscience</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Oceanography</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Earth system science</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Geoscience</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Anthropology</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Physical science</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Physics</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>General science</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>hot spot island</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>volcano</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>tectonic plates</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Earth</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>molten</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>magma</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>eruption</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>undersea</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>ocean</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>island</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Earth Processes</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Volcanoes and Plate Tectonics</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Earth Structure</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Rocks and Minerals</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Oceans and Water</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Geologic Time</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Heat and Temperature</dc:subject>
   <dc:subject>Conducting Investigations</dc:subject>
   <dc:language>en-US</dc:language>
   <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
   <lar:accessMode xsi:type="lar:ModeAcc">visual</lar:accessMode>
   <lar:accessMode xsi:type="lar:ModeAcc">tactile</lar:accessMode>
   <dct:educationLevel xsi:type="nsdl_dc:NSDLEdLevel">Upper Elementary</dct:educationLevel>
   <dct:educationLevel xsi:type="nsdl_dc:NSDLEdLevel">Middle School</dct:educationLevel>
   <dct:educationLevel xsi:type="nsdl_dc:NSDLEdLevel">High School</dct:educationLevel>
   <dct:educationLevel xsi:type="nsdl_dc:NSDLEdLevel">Informal Education</dct:educationLevel>
   <dct:audience xsi:type="nsdl_dc:NSDLAudience">Learner</dct:audience>
   <dc:type xsi:type="nsdl_dc:NSDLType">Activity</dc:type>
   <dc:type xsi:type="nsdl_dc:NSDLType">Model</dc:type>
   <dct:isPartOf>http://www.exo.net/~emuller/activities/index.html</dct:isPartOf>
   <dc:date xsi:type="dct:W3CDTF">2007</dc:date>
   <dc:creator>Eric Muller</dc:creator>
   <dc:contributor>The Exploratorium</dc:contributor>
   <dct:accessRights xsi:type="nsdl_dc:NSDLAccess">Free access</dct:accessRights>
   <dc:rights>Copyright 2007 Do Science</dc:rights>
   <dct:license>Owner license</dct:license>
   <lar:licenseProperty xsi:type="lar:LicProp">Terms of use unknown</lar:licenseProperty>
   <dct:rightsHolder>Do Science</dct:rightsHolder>
   <lar:metadataTerms>The following entity, University Corporation for Atmospheric Research (UCAR), has claims on the use of this metadata. This claim is as follows: The National Science Digital Library (NSDL), located at the University Corporation for Atmospheric Research (UCAR), provides these metadata terms: These data and metadata may not be reproduced, duplicated, copied, sold, or otherwise exploited for any commercial purpose that is not expressly permitted by NSDL. The entity provided more information at: http://nsdl.org/help/terms-of-use</lar:metadataTerms>
   <lar:metadataTerms>The National Science Digital Library (NSDL), located at the University Corporation for Atmospheric Research (UCAR), provides these metadata terms: These data and metadata may not be reproduced, duplicated, copied, sold, or otherwise exploited for any commercial purpose that is not expressly permitted by NSDL. More information is available at: http://nsdl.org/help/terms-of-use.</lar:metadataTerms>
</nsdl_dc:nsdl_dc>

    </metadata>
  </record>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not clear what exactly you want to access, but try something like:

```
from lxml import etree
doc=etree.parse( xmlfile )
ns={'dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/', 
  'oai': 'http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/'}
doc.xpath( '//dc:subject' , namespaces=ns ) # get all of the dc:subjects
doc.xpath( '//dc:*', namespaces=ns )  # get all elements in dc: namespace
# more specific path 
doc.xpath( '/oai:OAI-PMH/oai:ListRecords/oai:record/oai:metadata/*/dc:*', namespaces=ns )
x=doc.xpath( '/oai:OAI-PMH/oai:ListRecords/oai:record/oai:metadata/*' )
x[0].xpath( '*[contains(.,"Geo")]' )  # you can also call xpath from non document nodes
x[0].xpath( 'dc:subject/text()' , namespaces=ns ) # get the text of dc:subjects
```

And read some docs about xpath outside of the python or lxml docs. 
They tell you how to use xpath in python, but they aren't really an xpath tutorial.

Note that find(), findall() methods take [ElementPaths](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath), which are a sort of 
limited subset of xpath like expressions.

Comment: This works, thank you. However it seems xpath is slow when working with large files. Could you explain why? Iterating is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
for element in tree.findall(".//{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}subject"):
    print element
```

Comment: any idea how to do this with xpath?

Comment: Argument to `findall` IS Xpath, isn't it?

Comment: not sure to be honest. Code fails if I put it in xpath(). I have been reading on ways to use things like: xpath('/foo/bar').

Comment: `.xpath('//*/*/*/*/*/*')` bring me to the level I want, but I have tried  replacing `*` with what I think is a node name, but still not working

Comment: It is impossible to understand what you want. Please clearly specify result you want to achieve.